# Using Encrypted Ansible Password in Python Script

Tags: python, ansible

I am using Ansible to run a python script with parameters. One of these parameters are a user password

```
script: "{{ path_to_setup_py }} --username {{ username }} --password {{ password }} --ip {{ ip }} --hostname {{ hostname }}"
```

This is able to pull everything but the password, the password is a user input that is then encrypted.

```
name: password
prompt: Enter your password
private: yes
encrypt: sha512_crypt
confirm: yes
salt_size: 7
```

When the python script is ran, the password comes up as the hash value and doesn't use the actual password. How would I get this to decrypt the hash and then run it on the script?

Any help would be appreciated, I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the fine manual says](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html#encrypting-values-supplied-by-vars-prompt), using `encrypt:` is really a specialization for when you are going to just send that value down into the `user:` module, and not interact with it further.

If you merely want the password to not echo to the screen, that is what the `private: yes` controls

In short, unless you have a requirement that you didn't disclose in your question, the solution is to just remove the `encrypt:` and `salt_size:` parameters:

```yaml
  name: password
  prompt: Enter your password
  private: yes
  confirm: yes
```